# Is there a single line statement to return from a function only if a conditional is true?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

In C#, is there any syntactic sugar to do the following in a single statement (basically, a conditional return):

```cs
public SomeBaseType MyFunction()
{
    // Can the two statements below be combined into one?
    SomeBaseType something = SomeFunction();
    if ( something != null ) { return something; }
    // End of statements regarding this question.


    // Do lots of other statements...
    return somethingElseThatIsADerivedTypeThatDoesntMatter;
}
```

Comment: return SomeFunction();

Comment: return SomeFunction() ?? OtherFunction();

Comment: Is there any else? What is `something == null`?

Comment: This snippet wouldn't compile. You have a code path that has no returns.

Comment: Your question would be clearer with a [mcve], but assuming you want to continue with the rest of the method if the condition *isn't* met, then no, there's no syntactic sugar for that.

Comment: Question updated to provide more context.  I am attempting to do an early exit to a function if some condition exists, and this pattern will be repeated very often.  I am looking to see if I can provide an example pattern with the bare minimum lines of code that are repeated.

Comment: your scenario might benefit from special case: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html

Comment: @JonSkeet Hopefully, my update meets the minimal reproducible example.  Regardless of that, the assumption in the remainder of your comment is correct.  If the answer is no, there is no syntactic sugar for that, I am good with that as an answer and would mark that as an accepted answer if put forth as an answer instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no "conditional return statement" that either returns (based on a condition) or continues in the method, although I've occasionally wished for one too. You could write:

```
public SomeBaseType MyFunction()
{
    return SomeFunction() ?? LocalMethod();

    SomeBaseType LocalMethod()
    {  
        // Do lots of other statements...
        return somethingElseThatIsADerivedTypeThatDoesntMatter;
    }
}
```

... but that's really no clearer.